# UnknownHostexception using apache commons

Tags: android, apache, ftp, apache-commons

I am currently working with apache commons in my Project to gain access to my FTP Server.
Uploading a file is no problem at all, but If I want to download a file, I get an UnknownHost Exception what is strange because it is the same ftp server.

```
client.connect("ftp.liamissimo.li.ohost.de",21);
client.login("XXX", "XXX");
client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

This code works like this for uploading, but if I use it to download I got an UnknownHost exception.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Well, I saw there is no line marked, there is this instead:

Comment: `03-22 21:38:02.404: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(515): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ftp.android/com.ftp.android.Main}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.UnknownHostException`

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this and I got it to work by using the IP of the hostname instead of the actual hostname...

Comment: Thanks alot, got it to work now, even if now he is not finding my file -.-

Comment: Hmm. Sorry. That I do not know. Maybe its somthing in your code. When I was working with my FTP app I noticed FTP is really, really picky on what you type. Make sure all the paths are exactly as they should be. Dont forget to accept and push  the up arrow if I helped out! :)

Answer (score 0):

check permissions in manifest file.

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>